# How do I print list with in the list?

Tags: java

I'm trying to work out a way of printing up a ArrayList in java that follows a pattern like so:

**Input**

```
<a, B, B, B, a, But, But, a, yes, a> // ArrayList
```

**Output**

```
<a, <B,B,B>, a, <But,But>, a, <yes>,a> // ArrayList within the ArrayList
```

I need to print all strings in between 'a' should in separate list with in another list.
However, I'm completely stumped as to how I can achieve this. Please, can someone help me out? I have tried searching online for a similar problem, however, it's very difficult to phrase it correctly in a search.

Comment: Let forget about Java or programming. How would you do it by inspection, what you see? This will give you a foundation on how to write your code.

Comment: have you tried to iterate over the array?

Comment: @Y.Krishna please mind about accept an answer if it solve your problem, or just to thank those who spend time to answer you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may `iterate` over your first `List`, and then is one of the element inside is `Iterable` (`Set`,`List`, ...) you call `recursively` the same method on this `Iterable` object

```
public static void print(Iterable<Object> i) {
    for (Object o : i){
        if (o instanceof Iterable)
            print((Iterable) o);
        else
            System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

An example of how to use :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add(Arrays.asList("tt", "tt", 76));
    list.add("a");
    list.add(65);
    print(list);
}
```